# How to make default Firefox's start page (speed dial) dark

Tags: css, firefox

I believe I can change internal CSS. Or may be somebody already has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply css to your firefox browser with this method.
first find your firefox user profile based on your operating system. In linux userProfile directory is :

```
/home/--USER--/.mozilla/--something--.default/
```

then,make folder called "Chrome".

there are 2 files that can change css of your firefox,"userContent.css" and "userChrome.css".

userContent.css can apply css to your firefox tabs while userChrome.css apply to your firefox appearance,like developer tools and navbar.

So to change your start page(original name is about:home),make userContent.css file inside chrome folder. after all your directory tree should look like this:

```
/home/--USER--/.mozilla/firefox/--something--.default/chrome/userContent.css
```

then to change about:home style,use this code inside userContent.css:

```
  @-moz-document url("about:home"), url("about:newtab") {
       //insert css here
  }
```

it should work perfectly and i tested it but if anything happen,i would be happy to help you

---

**UPDATE**

userprofile directory on windows is :

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default
```

and mac OS:

```
Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default
```